# What does Carl mean when he says, "that son of a gun"?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, hachi-a-dogs-tale

In *Hachi: A Dog's Tale* , there is a scene about Hachi is waiting for his master for the first time outside the train station. And when Parker noticed that Hachi is there , he is excited and plays with Hachi. Then Carl (the staff in the train station)  sees him and Hachi playing , and says,

> that son of a gun....

What is the meaning when he says that?

The closest I could get is just when he says "that son of a gun....", he means "That lucky bastard ...." because he sees Hachi and the professor are happy together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both have different meanings.

**son of a gun**

Means a tough guy.

Example: In the  movie *The Avengers* when Iron-Man guides the missile into the portal, loses consciousness and the portal was about to close, he comes back to earth falling. At this time, Cap says "Son of a gun.", meaning Iron-Man is a tough guy (Can be interpreted in many other ways but this is mine.).

**That lucky bastard**

It is different from the above expression. For example, if a guy is dating hottest girl in the school, the other guys might call him "Lucky bastard", meaning he got lucky to date that girl.

In the movie *Hachiko*, Carl says Hachi a *son of a gun* because Hachi is tough and waits for his master at the station at the exact time when his master's train arrives.

Moments before that scene there's a conversation like this,

> -He's been here all day?
>
> -No... no, he's just rode up 2
>   minutes ago. He went right there.
>
> -You're kidding. You seen Cate?
>
> -I haven't seen her.

From the conversation, we can say that, Hachi reached station and waiting for the master in time without anyone's help. So, I think that's Carl way of telling Hachi a tough guy.

Answer (score 4):

Son of a gun, is a euphemism for Son of a bitch. In this case, it's a double entendre, as a dog is literally a son of a bitch, and the common use of the phrase to express disbelief for any reason.